# some confusion about minial polynomial.?

Tags: linear-algebra

let  $A =  \begin{bmatrix} c_1 & 0\\ 0 &c_2 \end{bmatrix}$

$B=\begin{bmatrix}c_1&0\\1&c_2\end{bmatrix}$

I thinks   Both A and B have  same  minimial  polynomial  because  both have  same  characteristics   polynomials...

Comment: This is only true as long as $c_1\neq c_2$ holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two $n{\,\times\,}n$ matrices have the same minimal poynomial, they have the same characteristic polynomial.

But the converse need not hold.

However, for an $n{\,\times\,}n$ matrix, the minimal and characteristic polynomials have the same set of distinct eigenvalues, hence in this case, if $c_1\ne c_2$, the polynomial $(x-c_1)(x-c_2)$ is the minimal and characteristic polynomial for both $A$ and $B$.

On the other hand, if $c_1=c_2 = c$, then $A$ and $B$ share the characteristic polynomial $(x-c)^2$, but the minimal polynomial for $A$ is $x-c$, while the minimal polynomial for $B$ is $(x-c)^2$.

Comment: if $c_1 = c_2 $ how  minimial polynomial  of  B is$ (x-c) ^2$as  it should  be (x-c)

Comment: The minimal polynomial must divide the characteristic polynomial, hence, since the characteristic polynomial of $B$ is $(x-c)^2$, the minimal polynomial of $B$ is either $x-c$ or $(x-c)^2$. But $B$ doesn't satisfy $x-c$, since $B-cI\ne 0$, hence the minimal polynomial of $B$ is $(x-c)^2$.

Comment: thanks   @quasi...